# Proxy / Decorator Design pattern scalability to a lot of methods

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, clean-code, clean-architecture

I'm trying to solve a common problem of logging each method that calls 3rd party operation and I don't understand how to scale it up.
Current implementation:

```
public class ElasticsearchClient {

    RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
            RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));

    public void createIndex() throws IOException {
        CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest("twitter");
        client.indices().create(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    }
}

public class ElasticsearchProxy {

    ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient();
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getSimpleName());

    public void createIndex() throws IOException {
        logger.info("Calling to method " + this.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() + " in ES");
        client.createIndex();
    }
}
```

As you can see now I only have 1 method - `createIndex()` but what if I have multiple methods - `reIndex()`, `deleteIndex()`, `getIndex()` and many more, for each of those methods I need to do:

```
    public void reIndex() throws IOException {
        logger.info("Calling to method " + this.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() + " in ES");
        client.reIndex();
    }

    public void deleteIndex() throws IOException {
        logger.info("Calling to method " + this.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() + " in ES");
        client.deleteIndex();
    }

    public void getIndex() throws IOException {
        logger.info("Calling to method " + this.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() + " in ES");
        client.getIndex();
}
```

I find it to be a crazy code duplication and it feels that there must be another way to do it so:

1. I will not repeat the `logger.info(...)` line
2. I will not have to copy each method in the client class to be in the proxy class as well, I would like to have an option to add a method in the client class that will be automatically exposed in the proxy class but with the log message.

Thanks

Comment: I was wondering why you need two classes (client and proxy) here?

Comment: I dont want to put the logging code in the client class. I want the client class to have only business related code, I want it to be clean.

Comment: Even if I put the logging in the client class, I need to repeat the call to the logger in each method which is a code duplication and error prone because someone can forget to call the logger. Having each method start with call to logger is code duplication, as I said, there must be a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dynamic proxies.

In Java the first step is to create an interface which contains the methods you want to log and forward.

```
interface If {
    void originalMethod(String s);
}
```

Let the target class implement that interface.

```
class Original implements If {
    public void originalMethod(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Then write an `InvocationHandler` which logs some text and calls the given `Method` on an instance of your choice (the business logic).

```
class Handler implements InvocationHandler {
    private final If original;

    public Handler(If original) {
        this.original = original;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
            throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        System.out.println("BEFORE");
        Object result = method.invoke(original, args);
        System.out.println("AFTER");
        return result;
    }
}
```

To get an object having the desired behavior you then use `Proxy.newProxyInstance`.

```
Original original = new Original();
Handler handler = new Handler(original);
If f = (If) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                If.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class[] { If.class },
                handler);
f.originalMethod("Hello");
```

Code in this example was taken (and slightly modified in order to return results from the handler which is not necessary here but in general it is) from here: https://dzone.com/articles/java-dynamic-proxy

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution is great and thanks for the reference to the article. This is exactly what I needed, a simple and scalable solution :)